# шаг в Seekbar в Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

Как сделать шаг в 0,05 в SeekBar ? Максимальное значение должно быть 1.5

Для 0,01 я просто делю на 100, а для 0,05?

Comment: Делить на 20?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спс, а то голова уже не варит,пора отдыхать..